# Ambiguous reference to member subscript

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
var dataRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let users = dataRef.child("users")
    users.queryOrderedByChild("Username").queryEqualToValue("notifactiontest").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        print(snapshot)

        if let token = snapshot.value["Users_Device_Token"] as? String{ <--- Error here.


        // do some stuff once
        }

    })
```

I am trying to get the FCM token associated with each user. When i print token i get the following:

```
Snap (users) {
    qIKBuX1IcIPdpMKml4Sh9MhIbPq1 =     {
        "Display_name" = notifactiontest;
        Username = notifactiontest;
        "Users_Device_Token" = "FCMTOKEN";
        "Users_Id" = qIKBuX1IcIPdpMKml4Sh9MhIbPq1;
    };
}
```

What i tried: Iterating trough each child and tried to mimic the iOS docs provided by Firebase.

Answer (score -1):

The `value` of an FDataSnapshot is an AnyObject. That means it has no *known* type. Thus you cannot subscript it (as in `value["Users_Device_Token"]`).

You seem to think that your `value` is a dictionary. You can certainly subscript a dictionary. But then in this situation you must tell Swift that this *is* a dictionary — that is, you must *cast* it as a dictionary before you try to subscript it.

Comment: Could you maybe pass some sample code as i tried to cast as a dictionary without any success